# Test async functions with python-rq

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fastapi, python-rq, pytest-asyncio

I am writing tests for a FastAPI app using pytest. I am using `pytest_asyncio` to test async functions.

```py
def get_queue():
  return Queue()

async def task_runner():
  ...

@app.post('/run-task')
async def run_task(queue: Queue = Depends(get_queue)):
  ...
  queue.enqueue(task_runner)
```

in the tests file I have the following:

```py
def get_test_queue():
    return Queue(is_async=False)

app.dependency_overrides[get_queue] = get_test_queue

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_run_task(client):
  await client.post('/run-task')
  # Assertions (requires task to be complete)
```

I set `is_async=False` as in the [docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/testing/#running-jobs-in-unit-tests)

When I run the tests I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

Does anyone has faced similar issue or has a work-around for this problem?

I tried to patch the `_execute` method in the `rq.job.Job` class but I am not used to `asyncio` library.